# cakephp 2.0 flash messages not displaying

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to display flash messages for errors however it not displaying i tried everything i could and researched it however didnt come with a solution, im quite new to cake so beer with me
thnks carts

Userscontroller

```
   public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been created'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages',  'action' => 'home'));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be created. Please, try again.'));

            }   
          }
          }
```

Default.ctp

```
     <div id="">
    <?php echo "Flash:" ?>
    <?php  echo $this->Session->flash();?>
```

element/failure

```
 <div class="flash flash-failure">
 <?php echo h($message); ?>
 </div>
```

view file

Form->create('User', array('action' => 'add'));?>

```
    <div class="firstname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class' => 'input01'));?>

    </div>


    <div class="lastname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('class' =>'input02'));?>

    </div>
    <div class = "firstname">

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('location', array('class' => 'input03'));?>

    </div>
    <div class="firstname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('class' =>'input03'));?>

    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'input03'));?>

    </div>

    <div class="lastname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('class' => 'input02'));?>

    </div>

    <div class="email">
    <?php   echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('label' => 'Confirm Password *', 'maxLength' => 255, 'title' => 'Confirm password', 'type'=>'password', 'class' =>'input03'));?>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your flash with your custom element, you will need to do it using this syntax.

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Error occured','failure');
```

The second parameter is the custom element which contain your flash html.

You may read more details of session flash here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html

Edited:
Also check if the code actually enters your is('post'), I dont have your full form and don't know which form send method you're currently using